# Resolution is being stupid. Help me?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, resolution, asus-laptop

I'm having trouble with a new computer I bought a few days ago. I have come to the conclusion that the resolution for the screen is configured too low. At the moment it is 1024x768 and I think it should be 1280x960, due to a message given at the resolution tab of the control panel.

It states: `If your resolution is below 1280x960, some items on the screen may not fit on the screen.`

The computer is an Asus A54H and runs 64-bit operating system with Windows 7 Home Premium.
This link has a screenshot of the screen at the moment, the icons and font are too big and are a little stretched.

Comment: It looks like the native resolution is 1366 x 768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max screen resolution in Asus A54H is 1,366x768.
Go to your desktop, right click > Screen Resolution and change it to 1366x786.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is why I asked. The highest I have is the resolution I posted.
http://imgur.com/a/fJAFF

Comment: Try [downloading](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=367&m=A54H&os=&hashedid=qRrJv389oYtZGCO1) & installing drivers. You will probably need the Intel Graphics Driver, under the VGA section there.

Comment: Nope, still no luck. "Windows has determined that this is the best driver for you" (the one I have installed). I added the next screenshot:http://imgur.com/a/fJAFF

Comment: Can you tell me what is the **exact** model of your laptop? A54H is just the prefix. I mean, it can be Asus A54H-SX080D or Asus A54H-so237v for example.

Comment: It's Asus A54H-SX254V. I'm not sure if thats an older model and that's why I can't update but anyway.

Comment: Weird, I can't find this model or even the A54H family at asus.com. Anyways, try to scan for driver using [this software](http://devicedoctor.com/).